# background image not working in html

Tags: java, html, jsp, filter

I gave a link to `forgotpassword.jsp` on my `index.html` page but after sometime i decided to change it so i created a new html file `forgotpassword.html` the body is similar in both the files but image is shown in `forgotpassword.jsp` but not in `forgotpassword.html` .  `forgotpassword.jsp` further goes to pass.jsp and i did the same thing for it also and created `pass.html` for it, same thing is happening in it `pass.jsp` is showing image but `pass.html` is not. Could someone tell me why this is happening ?
and please check the filter if there is something missing or wrong with it.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
        header {
            background-color:lightsteelblue;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
        nav {
            line-height:30px;
            height:300px;
            width:100px;
            float:left;
            padding:5px;
        }
        section {
            width:600px;
            float:right;
            padding:220px;
        }
        footer {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            clear:both;
            float:bottom; 
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;                                
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: lightsteelblue">        
    <header>
        <canvas  id="myCanvas" width="500" height="100" style="border:2px solid black; background-color:burlywood ">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

        <script>
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = "45px Arial";
            ctx.strokeText("File Tracking System", 50, 50);

        </script>  
    </header>
    <a href="forgotpass.jsp">Forgot Your Password</a>
    <section>
        <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">            
            Username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
            <br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"/>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

        </form>
        <img src="css/NSIC-logo1.png" width="537" height="267" alt="NSIC-logo1"/>
    </section>
    <footer>Copyright 2016 NSIC. All right reserved.</footer>        
</body>
</html>
```

forgotpass.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Forgot Password Page</title>
    <style>
        header {
            background-color:teal;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
        nav {
            line-height:30px;
            height:300px;
            width:120px;
            float:left;
            padding:5px;
        }
        section {
            width:800px;
            float:right;
            padding:130px;
        }
        footer {
            background-color:black;
            float:bottom;
            color:white;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
    <header><h3>File Tracking System!!</h3>
        <br>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <form action="forgotServlet" method="POST" >
            User Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="" size="20" />
            Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="20" />
            New Password:<input type="text" name="pass1" value="" size="20" />
            Repeat Password:<input type="text" name="pass2" value="" size="20" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </nav>
    <section><img src="css/NSIC-logo1.png" width="537" height="267" alt="NSIC-logo1"/></section>    
    <footer>
        Copyright 2016 NSIC. All right reserved.                             
    </footer>
</body></html>
```

forgotpass.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forgot Password Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
        header {
            background-color:teal;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
        nav {
            line-height:30px;
            height:300px;
            width:120px;
            float:left;
            padding:5px;
        }
        section {
            width:800px;
            float:right;
            padding:130px;
        }
        footer {
            background-color:black;
            float:bottom;
            color:white;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
    <header><h3>File Tracking System!!</h3>
        <br>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <form action="forgotServlet" method="POST" >
            User Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="" size="20" />
            Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="20" />
            New Password:<input type="text" name="pass1" value="" size="20" />
            Repeat Password:<input type="text" name="pass2" value="" size="20" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </nav>
    <section><img src="css/NSIC-logo1.png" width="537" height="267" alt="NSIC-logo1"/></section>    
    <footer>
        Copyright 2016 NSIC. All right reserved.                             
    </footer>
</body></html>
```

This is my AuthenticationFilter-

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

private ServletContext context;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
    this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    this.context.log("Requested Resource::" + uri);

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    if (session == null && !(uri.endsWith("html") || uri.endsWith("LoginServlet") || uri.endsWith("forgotpass.jsp") || uri.endsWith("doesnotexist.jsp") || uri.endsWith("pass.jsp"))) {
        this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
        res.sendRedirect("index.html");
    } else {
        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    //close any resources here
}

}
```

Comment: please try to load image using `jquery/java-Script` only. hope this might work to you. Thanks

Comment: same folder for both jsp and html files? check what absolute url both pages are pointing to, for this image.

Comment: Check in your developer tools.

Comment: Same folder is used for both and url is showing same for both pages

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: [chat-conversation-with-rahul](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116215/) The problem is real. I was unable to solve it.**

There is a problem with File Structure of your HTML and JSP Files. As @aksappy commented, check in developer tools(`CTRL+SHIFT+I` for chrome) for `console` errors. Also, check the `src` attribute of your `<img>` tag on both `html` and `jsp` file from developer tools.

Your code is working perfectly.

**Proof**

JSP IMAGE
[image: JSP IMAGE]

HTML IMAGE
[image: HTML IMAGE]

Comment: If i use chrome then It is giving a resource not found error                                                            Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (21:16:01:894 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8080/test9/css/index.html                                             but with internet explorer no error is shown

Comment: try [this](http://imgur.com/p3Zg1sX) for both the JSP and HTML file. See if it Highlights in Elements tab in Developer Tools. Otherwise, there is a problem which indicates that both the files aren't in same folder. Are you using Netbeans on Windows?

Comment: Also, try removing `css/` from `<img>` src attribute, because your `index.html` is inside `css` folder.

Comment: Yes i am using netbeans on windows and it is getting highlighted

Comment: Go to `My Documents > NetbeansProjects > 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME' > web` folder and see if both(HTML&JSP) files are in same folder. Tried removing `css/` on `<img>` src attributes? Also, try after clearing browser `cache` and `cookies`.

Comment: The same problem is with my index page (and error msg is shown)right now i am using forgotpass.jsp so image is there. When i run the app there is no image on index page, i click on the forgotpassword link it goes to to jsp page and image is there when i go back the image seems to appear on index.html , i close the browser run the it again now there is no error msg for index.html NOW i login and then logout the image has disappeared again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116215/discussion-between-rupinderjeet47-and-rahul-gupta).

Comment: I removed css/ from <img> , put the image directly in web folder it is still not working